# How to specialize constructor of template class in another class?

Tags: c++, class, c++11, templates, template-specialization

Consider the following classes:

```
// Class1.hpp
class Class1 {};

// Class2.hpp
class Class2 {};

// ClassA.hpp
#include "Class1.hpp"
#include "Class2.hpp"

class A {
private:
    enum class Enum {
        Enum1,
        Enum2
    };

    struct B {
        B(Enum argEum) : enumMember{argEnum} {}
        Enum enumMember;
    };

    template <class T>
    struct C : public B {}
};
```

Now I would like to make the following specializations of the constructor of C:

```
C<Class1>::C() : B{Enum::Enum1} {}
C<Class2>::C() : B{Enum::Enum2} {}
```

From what I tried I guess I have to place the specializations outside of the class definition of class A, but I don't really know how to do it.

Comment: Could you please *fix* the many issues in the sample not related to your question? Your pseudo code is too pseudo. And it's a bit much to expect an answer to address all of that probably (but not definitely) unrelated stuff too.

Comment: Any reason not to use a simple `if` (`constexpr`) with `std::is_same`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put a specialization anywhere a declaration of the templated entity may appear. Namespace scope is fine, but it requires you to fully qualify the thing your are specializing.

Furthermore, you may not specialize a member that wasn't declared in the primary template first. So with those two points in mind:

```
// In the class
template <class T>
struct C : public B {
    C() = delete;
};

// In namespace scope

template<>
A::C<Class1>::C() : B{Enum::Enum1} {}

template<>
A::C<Class2>::C() : B{Enum::Enum2} {}
```

And a [live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/44af08fd38bb180a) to refer to.